how come the finally block runs after the result in this code?
def tricky_generator(n):
    for i in range(n):
        try:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                yield i // 2
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Odd value: {i}")
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            yield -1
        finally:
            print(f"Finally block executed for i={i}")

gen = tricky_generator(5)
result = [next(gen) for _ in range(5)]
print("Result:", result)

The result is supposed to be printed at the end, but somehow a finally block i = 4 is executed after it for some reason even though all the finally blocks should be executed before the result

This question is similar to: try-finally in Python 3 generator. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You only pulled 5 items from the iterator.  Thus, the last thing the function did was the yield i//2 statement.  The function was suspended right there, while the main program did its thing.  It never got a chance to execute any more until the cleanup when the program finished.
